# How can I enter quotes or apostrophes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Trying to enter the following text fails:

```
MERGE (people:People {Person:'Abe N. O'Sullivan'})
```

Replacing the apostrophe with a ’ works, but I wonder if there is a more ellegant solution.

Comment: You can also quote them with a backslash. Or use parameters `MERGE (people:People {Person:{name}})` params: `{"name":"Abe N. O'Sullivan"}`

Answer (score 5):

Use double quotes, and it will work fine:

```
MERGE (people:People {Person:"Abe N. O'Sullivan"})
```

Note if this were the name of a property, you can use backticks to escape the name of a property that has spaces or special characters in it.  For text literals, you can surround them with either single or double quotes.  If you want to put a quote inside of a text literal quote, you either need to use the other kind of quote to surround the string, or you need to escape it with backslash, I believe.